# Custom Setting of Custom Metadata in Managed Package

Tags: apex, trigger, customsetting, custom-metadata

I am deploying a Managed Package with a few APEX Triggers in it. Each organization that installs the Managed Package should be able to determine which Triggers run so I need a way to provide a "Setting" to Enable/Disable each Trigger from running.

Would it be best to do this with a Custom Setting or the New Custom Metadata Type? Could anyone give me some examples on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use Custom Metadata Type because of the following reasons

- Custom metadata records travel with your object which is not possible with custom settings
- Custom metadata is customizable, deployable, packageable, and upgradeable application metadata.
- Because the records are metadata, you can migrate them using packages or Metadata.API tools.
- Custom metadata fields are manageable, which means that the developer of a type can decide who can change field values after they are deployed to a subscriber organization.

  - Locked after release—For any record of the type, the value of the field is immutable after deployment, even on the developer organization where the record was created.
  - Subscriber editable—Anyone with the correct permissions can change the value of the field at will. Any changes the developer deploys do not overwrite values in the subscriber's organization.
  - Upgradable—The developer of a record can change the value of the field by releasing a new version of the custom metadata package. The subscriber can’t change the value of the field.

Following table will do clear comparison with custom settings.

[image]